# Google App Engine: how to tell sort location for a user value?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sorting

In my `Main` model I have a `total_value` and I sort with this value. When a user enters a value I wish to tell the user the order of his `total_value`. How do I do this?

In other words, if `total_value`s in database are 5,8,10,25 and a user enters a `total_value` of 15 how do I tell him that he will be in the 4th place?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a query which counts the number of values smaller than the user's `total_value`.  This may be slow if there are many `Main` entities.  In that case, you may wish to only count the first `N` values smaller, and then stop (e.g., tell the user they are ranked 1000+).  Your query might look like this:

```
# get the rank of total_value compared to existing total_values (up to 1,000)
rank = Main.all().filter('total_value <', total_value).count(1000) + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

The count-based solutions David and Rahul propose will only work efficiently for small numbers of entities. If you want to determine position inside a large list, you want something like the [ranklist](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-ranklist/) project.

Comment: Thanks for this reference. `Main` may have a large number of items but I am fetching only 25 and I need to know the rank within 25 items. I assume `count()` is ok for this purpose.

Comment: @Zeynel Yes, it'll be fine for small result sets like that.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the count of number of entities that have `total_value` less than or equal to the current users `total_value`.

You could use the count() method to do so (on a Query object).